# [assembly: attribution ?? custom assembly attributes that executes code

Tags: c#, syntax, assemblies, custom-attributes

Does anyone have a name for this syntax on the [assembly....] line.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;

[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
namespace MyFirstNHibernateSite.Models
{
    public class NHibernateISession
    {
```

What is happening technically with the call to log4net?
Do you have a reference link that I can read up?  Or at lease a name for this syntax?

I understand custom assembly attributes. I don't understand how this relates to executing the code in log4net's configuration methods.  is this like an uber-global attachment of log4net to everything in my assembly's execution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When log4net assembly initializes, it searches for such attribute on the assembly level of your assembly and reads the provided values of properties (such as Watch=true) from it. According to those values, it decides how to configure the logging.

Comment: Edin.  Thanks. I know that.  I'm looking for deeper technical details on what the syntax does in general; using log4net as an example.

Comment: The syntax does nothing itself. It is just an attribute that decorates your assembly. It is up to others (in this case log4net assembly) to inspect that information and act accordingly. How log4net will act is unknown to us just from the attribute itself. For that we would must consult documentation.

Comment: I get the attribution.  But it appears to be executing log4net too.  I put the line in, compile and run adn lo44net does what I expect it too.  I remove the line , no other changes, re-complile & run and log4net falls silent.

Comment: log4net must have certain mechanism implemented to evaluate if the loaded assembly has this attribute set. For example it could hook up to the `AppDomain.AssemblyLoad` and check the assemblies which get loaded or it might inspect the executing assembly for this attribute as soon the log4net assembly itself loads. The real mechanism I do not know and would have to dig into the log4net documentation or code. But if it is none of the above two, it is something similar indeed.

Comment: OOOoooo  You're right.  I was through by that I was calling log4net.config() is TWO different places.  When I removed BOTH then my log4net fell silent.